# how do i compute the average value of every n row of an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array (`a`) and need to find the average of every 4th row.

Can I use `np.mean` to do this?
I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```py
means = np.mean(a, step=4, axis=1)
print(means)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with

```
means = np.mean(a[::4], axis=1)
```

Where `a[::4]` selects every 4th row from a.